# Rejecting an association because deserialization of the encoded handle failed. DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth

I am working through the DotNetOpenAuth samples, and implementing an openID provider and relying party.

Essentially it's very similar to to the provided DotNetOpenAuth samples, except I am using MVC 4, therefore Razor, and thus not using the *IdentityEndpoint* control as used in the sample. ( I am writing the provider headers out in a partial view instead ). Also hosted in IIS 7.5.

I am getting to the point where the user is signing on, and the OP is redirecting back to the Relying Party, which is getting the following error, from the logs:

> DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: Missing decryption key for bucket "https://localhost/dnoa/association_handles" handle "3tg1"
>   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ErrorUtilities.VerifyProtocol(Boolean condition, String unformattedMessage, Object[] args)
>   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.DataBagFormatterBase`1.CalculateSignature(Byte[] bytesToSign, String symmetricSecretHandle)
>   a....

I am not sure if it helps but the two headers preceding the error are:

```
Signing these message parts:    
claimed_id: http://www.sampleOpenIDProvider.com/user/justpartofthecrowd   
identity: http://www.sampleOpenIDProvider.com/user/justpartofthecrowd   
assoc_handle: he9m!IAAAAD43Voo3-zQng-ZVSKb9ryFVSIKDLJj4Ph_I9W64ypFCQQAAAAFlZWUQzOJQfO70Pvud2a--auCE7HKkFjBM45HXlpJixLEmtdgd8YPBMckvUFnIPqHBbaAk7mkhI8lDVPoKekUW   
op_endpoint: http://www.sampleOpenIDProvider.com/OpenId/Provider   
return_to: http://www.samplemobilephonecompany.com/User/Authenticate?ReturnUrl=Index&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sampleOpenIDProvider.com   
response_nonce: 2012-12-03T23:59:05ZCqMBPIFL    
Base64 representation of signed data: 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  
Signature: kw4f92CpwFbXgUkLs+Pf+5cFrtEzmE9KpxHgTYwi1tQ=
```

and

```
After binding element processing, the received IndirectSignedResponse (2.0) message is:    
openid.sig: kw4f92CpwFbXgUkLs+Pf+5cFrtEzmE9KpxHgTYwi1tQ=   
openid.signed: claimed_id,identity,assoc_handle,op_endpoint,return_to,response_nonce   
openid.assoc_handle: he9m!IAAAAD43Voo3-zQng-ZVSKb9ryFVSIKDLJj4Ph_I9W64ypFCQQAAAAFlZWUQzOJQfO70Pvud2a--auCE7HKkFjBM45HXlpJixLEmtdgd8YPBMckvUFnIPqHBbaAk7mkhI8lDVPoKekUW   
openid.invalidate_handle: 3tg1!IAAAALLyXKaShsmSDmEaKWxiBCi7-a8Nso0tyNaPKVqi52KuQQAAAAHvnjGT2Gt-_iWlSTpmBgthNS8s2Dxs6-pQG6rzYrFqgA5mp_T_HPcaJ6BchUsN9Lx2uH7jssuSAq0xbae7lb1r   
openid.op_endpoint: http://www.sampleOpenIDProvider.com/OpenId/Provider   
openid.return_to: http://www.samplemobilephonecompany.com/User/Authenticate?ReturnUrl=Index&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sampleOpenIDProvider.com   
openid.response_nonce: 2012-12-03T23:59:05ZCqMBPIFL   
openid.mode: id_res   
openid.ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0   
openid.claimed_id: http://www.sampleOpenIDProvider.com/user/justpartofthecrowd   
openid.identity: http://www.sampleOpenIDProvider.com/user/justpartofthecrowd   
ReturnUrl: Index   dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier: http://www.sampleOpenIDProvider.com
```

I guess this will only mean anything to those that have implemented dotnetopenauth, but worth a shot!

Comment: What, if any `IOpenIdApplicationStore` have you supplied to your `OpenIdRelyingParty` class?

Comment: Hi, I am not using any IOpenIdApplicationStore. Just instantiating that class using the parameterless constructor as per the DotNetOpenAuth sample. I don't if this helps but the relying party code is the the dotnetopenauth sample, except that it is hosted in IIS. It's the opendID provider sample that I've recreated in MVC4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accidentally fixed it, while searching for through google groups, and reading another question where the ever helpful Andrew Arnott suggested checking that all openID endpoints are reachable without authorization.

So I checked my code, and I had the following statement in my RegisterGlobalFilters:

```cs
filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
```

I was using that with the **[AllowAnonymous]** attribute on all controllers or actions that were being used for openID. Or so I thought, because removing the global filter, and then explicitly adding the **[Authorize]** attribute only to the areas that required authorization fixed the issue.